# How to set a default preference only when the extension installs

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using firefox SDK for extension development. Firstly, I do not want to expose this preference to user. I just want this preference to be used for inside extension code for some handling.

My usecase is that I want to reset that preference only when the user re-install the extension. I don't want to reset the preference when the user restart firefox or disable/enable extension.

One way that I tried was to use get/set APIs of "preferences-service" inside main.js code. But main.js code would run everytime I restart firefox or disable/enable the extension. This re-writes the initial value for the preference as the main.js code runs again.

Is there a way using SDK that we reset the preference value only during installs and not during firefox restart & disable/enable of extension?

Answer (score 0):

The `self` module exposes the [`loadReason`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/self.html#loadReason) property.

Answer (score 0):

`loadReason` is also exposed as a parameter to your addon's call to `main()`.  See [Listening for Load and Unload](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/load-and-unload.html) for details.

Comment: This does not seem to be a proper answer for the question. Links to the documentation can be added as a comment.